# How to get the Different User Story's like Instagram and any other Social media app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

here is my database [first Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWVCM.png)

[2nd Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0t14.png)

[finlal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQIbt.png)
whenever user uploads story the "stroyAdded" feild gets true thats how Iam fetching the list of the user who have uploaded the story

here is the code of the particular

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .where("stroyAdded", isEqualTo: true)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
          ConnectionState.active) {
        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var data =FirebaseFirestore.instance.
              collection("users").doc(snapshot.data!.docs[index].
              get("uid")).collection("Stories").snapshots();
              print(snapshot.data!.docs.length);
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 10),
                child: StoryCircle(
                    () {
                       
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>StoryPage();
                    },
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                        .get("profile"),
                    snapshot.data!.docs.length),
              );
            });
      }
    } else {
      // No data
    }
    return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  })
```

[My desire output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gd8r.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you only want to show the storys from the last 24h like other solical media plattforms. In this case the best way to query all the stories from the diffrent collections would be to us a singel query with a collection group query.

You can read more about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#java_30

My solution:

```
    db.collectionGroup("Stories").whereGreaterThan("time", yourDateObject - 24h)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Everything is good but the problem is that whenever I am  fetching the story in a storycircle it is creating different circle for all the different storyItems(like photo text),what I want is that all the story should be shown in the same circle of a perticuller user , I hope you got Me !